# Driver giving Null point exception

Tags: java, selenium, cucumber

The below code was trying to run without example keyword in cucumber, but the output is dispalying as a Null pointer error

```
WebDriver driver;
    @Given("^user is alredy in login page$")
    public void user_is_alredy_in_login_page() {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\swagatika.mohapatra\\OneDrive - Qualitest Group\\Desktop\\selenium\\DRIVER\\D-v-88-chrome\\chromedriver.exe");

        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("https://opensource-demo.orangehrmlive.com/");
        driver.manage().window().maximize();

    }


    @Given("^user enters \"(.*)\" and \"(.*)\"$")
    public void user_enters_valid_user_name(String username, String password) {

        this.driver = driver;
        driver.findElement(By.id("txtUsername")).sendKeys(username);
        driver.findElement(By.id("txtPassword")).sendKeys(password);


    }
```

console output in Debug mode -

```
this = {LoginStepDefination@3223} 
 driver = null
username = "Admin"
password = "admin123"
this.driver = null
driver = null
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
```

you are redeclaring driver as a local varaible in first step instead:

```
WebDriver driver;
    @Given("^user is alredy in login page$")
    public void user_is_alredy_in_login_page() {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\swagatika.mohapatra\\OneDrive - Qualitest Group\\Desktop\\selenium\\DRIVER\\D-v-88-chrome\\chromedriver.exe");

        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("https://opensource-demo.orangehrmlive.com/");
        driver.manage().window().maximize();

    }


    @Given("^user enters \"(.*)\" and \"(.*)\"$")
    public void user_enters_valid_user_name(String username, String password) {
        this.driver.findElement(By.id("txtUsername")).sendKeys(username);
        this.driver.findElement(By.id("txtPassword")).sendKeys(password);
    }
```

Comment: @Greg thanks for updating i thought he is passing a local driver argument to that method

Comment: No problem. I was right in the middle of posting an answer when I saw yours.

Comment: Note to author you don't need to use this here as it will be added explicitly by compiler as there is no variable with same name in that method